# Reading a File in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, file, class, properties, attributes

I'm working on a program and am supposed to follow this set of directions:

```
1. Create a class with the following (This may or may not be done correctly, I'm not sure)
     Attributes
        strName As String
        dblSalary As Double
     Properties
       name- can be any string
       salary- can only be positive numbers, if the number is negative, set it to equal 10
     computeSalary(intMonths As Integer)
        When called, the salary * number of months is returned.
2. Read in a file selected by the user. (I think I have this part done correctly)
     Must be a txt file
     Filter open file dialog to only show txt files
3. Once the file is read in, the following menu items are available 
     Show Employee Names
         Another form pops up displaying all the employee names read from the file in  a listbox
     Show Employee Salaries
         Another form pops up displaying all the employee salaries read from the file in a listbox
     Show an Employee
         Another form pops up displaying all the employees names read from the file in a listbox
         When a name is selected from the listbox, labels are filled showing that employees' name and salary.
         In this form there's an option to calculate an employees' salary for a given number of months
             When this button is pushed, an input pop up is shown and the user is asked to enter the number of months for which they'd like the salary to be calculated and displays the salary for the given number of months. 
                For example, if an employee makes $1,000 per month and the user enters a 3, $3,000 would be displayed.
```

I have a fairly decent portion of the code written so far and it works correctly for what is written (as far as I can tell anyway). The open file dialog only shows text files, when I select a file the correct menu options are un-greyed out (yes I know that's not a word ha), and clicking each of those menu items takes me to their corresponding forms. So I'm hoping that everything else will fall into place when I get this question answered.

The problem I'm having is reading in the file in such a way that only the names or only the salaries will be displayed in the correct listbox. I'd like to do this in the simplest way possible without having to change a big chunk of my current code if that's at all possible.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.IO

Public Class Main

    Private Sub open_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles open.Click
        Dim open As New OpenFileDialog
        open.Filter = "text files |*.txt|All Files|*.*"
        open.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)

        If open.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim selectedFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(open.FileName)
            showNames.Enabled = True
            showSalaries.Enabled = True
            showEmployee.Enabled = True
        End If

        Dim line As String
        Using reader As New StreamReader(open.OpenFile)
            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                line = reader.ReadLine
                Console.WriteLine(line)
            End While
        End Using

    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Me.Close()
        Names.Close()
        Salaries.Close()
        frmTotal.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub showNames_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles showNames.Click
        Names.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub showSalaries_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles showSalaries.Click
        Salaries.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub showEmployee_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles showEmployee.Click
        frmTotal.Show()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Project9

    Dim strName As String
    Dim dblSalary As Double

    Private Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return strName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            strName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Property Salary() As Double
        Get
            Return dblSalary
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            If dblSalary < 0 Then
                dblSalary = 10
            End If
            dblSalary = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Private Function computeSalary(intMonths As Integer) As Double
        Dim dblTotal As Double = dblSalary * intMonths

        Return dblTotal
    End Function

End Class
```

Here's my text file

```
Steve McGarret  
1500.00
Danny Williams 
1300.00
Matthew Casey
1700.00
Kelly Severide
1750.00
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, also if you notice anything wrong pertaining to the classes, attributes, properties, or function please let me know, I've never worked with any of those before so am not sure that I have it done properly.

Comment: Hard to answer this question without knowing what is inside the text file. Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Sorry about that, just updated my question with my text file

Comment: the text file is in pairs, so read a line to a Name var and the next to a salary var and use them to create a Project9 instance (after you fix it, right now you cannot get or set the name or salary).  So expand the streamreader loop.  the bigger question is where the emps are stored...consider a `List(Of Project9)`

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem is I'm really new at this and have no idea how to do any of that ha.

Comment: instead of one single `Line` variable, read a Name then a Salary to use to create a Project9 instance.  there are several things to fix in the class first though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class can be the 'masters' of the data they manage.  As such, whatever `Salaries.Show` and `Names.Show` are (and whereever they are), these can be internalized to the Project9 class. you almost certainly want the properties Public so you can access them.

One tip, as of VS2012, you no longer need to declare simple props that way:

```
Public Property Name As String
Public Property Salary as Decimal       ' money almost always should be Decimal
```

The backing fields (e.g. strName) are no longer needed as VS creates a _Name variable for you.  When you have something like the salary qualification, then you need the full/non auto prop declarations.  The `computeSalary` function is also private so you cant call it externally.

You can (should) also add a constructor to fill in the needed values when you create a new instance (avoids having to set the name and salary each time individually):

```
Public Sub New(n As String, s As Decimal)
     strName = n
     Salary = s      ' use the code in the prop setter
End Sub
```

There is nothing in your code for reading the text file (we dont know its layout) nor for posting to the listbox, but here is a tip:

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
     Return strName &  "   "   & decSalary.ToString
End Sub
```

Add that function to the Project9 class and modify it to return whatever you need.  That way, to populate the listbox, you just add a Project9 instance to it:

```
 Dim emp As New Project9("Beth", 1000)       ' bad name
 ' creates an emp with the name and salary
 ListBox.Items.Add(emp)
```

the listbox will use the ToString function for display/  To show just the Names or Salaries, use those Props

**EDIT**

```
    Dim newName As String
    Dim newSal As string
    Dim emp As Project9      ' which is crying out for a new name
    Using reader As New StreamReader(open.OpenFile)
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            newName = reader.ReadLine
            newSal = reader.ReadLine

            emp = New Project9(newName, convert.ToDecimal(newSal))
            ' now, you need somewhere, something to store emp in               

            Console.WriteLine(line)
        End While
    End Using
```

Alternatively, if the text lines were "Ziggy Dunbar, 1500.00", you could read one line per loop interation, split it at "," to get the data.  As is, if the file has a name with no salary, it will get out of synch and crash.

Comment: So on the properties are you saying there's no need for the Get and Set portions (sorry, I didn't even know what a property was until this week so have never used them)? Also, on the Dim emp portion of your answer, what is it's purpose since I'm reading info from a file so am not actually adding anything to it?

Comment: For storing emp, would that be like the listbox, or an array?

Comment: Show Employees and Show Employee Names are 2 of the forms, Show Employee is the fourth form where the user can select an employee and calculate the salary based on a certain number of months, and Show Employee Names just displays the names from the file in a non-selectable listbox.

Comment: This is soooo much more complicated than I was hoping it'd be haha.

Comment: Ok, I've made it to C, how would I go about fixing the properties?

Comment: Is there any particular place in the code that I should create the constructor?

Comment: Also, when you say to use the code from the setter prop, what code would that be exactly? Sorry, I'm REALLY not good at programming.